# Update other tables when new row inserted in lead table same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

A complete novice here with coding, so some thorough guidance will be very much appreciated!

I have two tables and have created a Command button which adds a new row to the lead table (Table1).

What I need to do is for the second, third and fourth tables (Table2,3,4) to be updated with a new row and with the same information in Column C when a new row is inserted in the lead table.

So far this is the code I have for the Command button which adds new rows to the Table1, i.e. lead table.

```
Range("B15:P15").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
```

[See table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AreTM.png)

Comment: Presumably you can just run similar lines for the other tables. What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest that rather than using sorting to group your tables, you use [ListObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject)? If you do this, there is a default collection of them for each sheet and you can easily implement adding rows to each table.

Code to do so would look something along the lines of

```
Sub add_rows()

    Dim tws     As Worksheet, _
        lo      As ListObject, _
        lr      As ListRow, _
        iter    As Long
        
    
    Set tws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets()
    
    '' treat all tables the same
    For Each lo In tws.ListObjects
        Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add
        '' example of how to set listrow data
        Let lr.Range(1, 1).Resize(1, 5) = [{1,2,3,4,5}]
    Next lo
       
    '' or
    
    '' treat each table differently
    For iter = 1 To tws.ListObjects.Count
        Set lo = tws.ListObjects.Item(iter)
        Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add
        
        Select Case iter
            Case 1
                '' do a first thing
            Case 2
                '' do a second thing
            Case 3
                '' do a third thing
            Case Else
                '' do something gneric
        End Select
    Next iter    
End Sub
```

where the only major change you would need to do to your excel file would be to select each table, and press `ctrl + T` to convert it